# How to avoid the invalid paramet topic Name for aws sns?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm a beginner with aws sns notification and i tryed to setup my notification on my node Js .

I add my credentials but it seems to have a problem with my TopicArn which i don't understand because i copy and past from my aws console

also my code :

```
// import aws
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");


AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'ACCES KEY ID',
  secretAccessKey: SECRET KEY,
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

var params = {
  Message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT', /* required */
 
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:025697195090:app/APNS_SANDBOX/Youklap'
};



// Create promise and SNS service object
var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
publishTextPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(`Message ${params.Message} sent to the topic ${params.TopicArn}`);
    console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });


AWS.config.getCredentials(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
  else {
    console.log("Access key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
    console.log("Region: ", AWS.config.region);
  }
});
```

and my error :

```
 code: 'InvalidParameter',
  time: 2021-05-06T09:26:53.916Z,
  requestId: 'ce4d6cff-b326-522d-8dca-35f20bbb78bd',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 81.86233324382624
} InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Topic Name
```

Comment: Topic name only allows alphanumeric characters and underscore(_), hyphen(-). So 'app/APNS_SANDBOX/Youklap' is an invalid name.

Comment: thanks @gsswain apparently the problem was more about the permissions of the user's group on aws. it's working well now